# Search for a string in memory

Tags: c, char, unsigned-char

I'm trying to get this code to work, from [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_Management_BIOS#Locating_the_SMBIOS_Entry_Point_Table)

```
    char *mem = (unsigned char *) 0xF0000;
    int length, i;
    unsigned char checksum;
    while ((unsigned int) mem < 0x100000) {
        if (mem[0] == '_' && mem[1] == 'S' && mem[2] == 'M' && mem[3] == '_') {
            length = mem[5];
            checksum = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                checksum += mem[i];
            }
            if(checksum == 0) break;
        }
        mem += 16;
}
```

There are some type errors, like cant init char* with unsigned char*.

when I try to replace `char *` with `unsigned char *` int first line I cant use [] notation, how can I use `memcmp` with this code?

Comment: What error messages do you get, and on which lines?

Comment: Why can't you use the [] notation with `unsigned char*`?

Comment: gives exc_bad_access on that line

Comment: Please update your question to make it more clear. First, you are assigning an `unsigned char*` to a `char *`, which causes a compiler error about incompatible types. Then, if you declare mem as `unsigned char *` your code will be formally correct, but causes _exc_bad_access_ **when running**. This means that you can't access an arbitrary memory region from within a userland process. Look for physical and virtual memory addresses and how to handle them in userland processes.

Comment: i found that this was incorrect method for my system, i dont need it any more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code failed to work because it is incorrect way of finding smbios entry point structure address on an EFI machine,

Answer (score 2):

In the first line, you cast to `unsigned char*`, but try assigning to `char*`. Why not cast to `char*` directly?

I'm assuming you are working on some embedded system code, since with multitasking operating systems, simply accessing hard-coded memory locations will cause your program to crash.

Comment: It will crash because in most systems you are not allowed to read memory that doesn't belong to the current process